# Hide only Page Navigation in Datatable

Tags: datatables

I want to hide only page navigation in data table server side processing,How can i achieve this?.Please refer screenshot?[image]

Answer (score 0):

Alter your table initialization call to use the [**dom**](https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom) option and don't add "p", like this:

```
$("example").DataTable({
    "dom": "lftir"
});
```

Hope that helps.